Probability that $x,y,z$ all $< 0.5$

Given $x+y+z=1$, what is probability that $x,y,z$ are all less than $0.5$?

My solution:
Since $x+y+z=1$, we can model this as a tetrahedron with coordinates $(1,0,0), (0,1,0),$ and $(0,0,1)$. Now, we need to find the probability that $x,y,$ and $z$ lie in the tetrahedron spanned by $(0.5,0,0),(0,0.5,0),$ and $(0,0,0.5)$. This is just $\frac{\text{Volume of tetrahedron with edge length = 0.5}}{\text{Volume of tetrahedron with edge length = 1}}$.
Therefore, the probability that $x,y,$ and $z$ are all less than $0.5$ is,
$$\frac{\frac{0.5^3}{6\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{1^3}{6\sqrt{2}}} = 12.5\%$$
Is my approach correct?

Model as a two-dimensional triangle, not a three-dimensional tetrahedron.

Can you tell me why we’re considering this as a 2D triangle despite having 3 coordinates? And why it’s working?

I see there is an accepted answer already. But there is no mention of any probability distributions of the variables in the problem as stated. For all we know, we could be rolling dice with faces labeled with various fractions.

I believe it follows a Uniform~(0,1) distribution.

Axes are $x$, $y$, and $z$:  Answer $1/4$

